# Database design for summarized data

Tags: sql, mysql, ruby-on-rails, database-design, postgresql

I have a new table I'm going to add to a bunch of other summarized data, basically to take some of the load off by calculating weekly avgs.

My question is whether I would be better off with one model over the other.  One model with days of the week as a column with an additional column for price or another model as a series of fields for the DOW each taking a price.

I'd like to know which would save me in speed and/or headaches?  Or at least the trade off.

IE.

```
ID   OBJECT_ID   MON  TUE  WED  THU  FRI  SAT  SUN   SOURCE
```

OR

```
ID   OBJECT_ID   DAYOFWEEK   PRICE   SOURCE
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would give the first preference to the following aggreate model:

```
ID | OBJECT_ID | DATE       | PRICE  | SOURCE 
---+-----------+------------+--------+--------
1  | 100       | 2010/01/01 | 10.00  | 0
2  | 100       | 2010/01/02 | 15.00  | 0
3  | 100       | 2010/01/03 | 20.00  | 0
4  | 100       | 2010/01/04 | 12.00  | 0
```

You would then be able to aggreate the above data to generate averages for every week/month/year very easily and relatively quickly.

To get the list of weekly averages, you would be able to do the following:

```
SELECT WEEK(date), AVG(price) FROM table GROUP BY WEEK(date);
```

For some further examples, the following query would return the average price on Sundays:

```
SELECT AVG(price) FROM table WHERE DAYOFWEEK(date) = 1;
```

Or maybe get the average daily price for the 8th week of the year:

```
SELECT AVG(price) FROM table WHERE WEEK(date) = 8;
```

It would also be quite easy to get monthly or yearly averages:

```
SELECT MONTH(date), AVG(price) FROM table GROUP BY MONTH(date);
```

I would only opt for more de-normalized options like the two you proposed if the above aggregations would still be too expensive to compute.

Answer (score 2):

I would vote for the second. With the first, you would need some contraints to ensure that any row has only one of `MON, TUE, WED, THU, FRI, SAT, SUN`. Of course, with the second,  you might need some additional reference data to define the Days of the Week, to populate `DAYOFWEEK`.

**UPDATE:**

Ok it wasn't clear there would always be a price for every day. In that case my point about constraints isn't so valid. I'd still prefer the second model though, it seems better normalized. I don't know enough about this case now to say if this is a good time to cast off some good normalization practices for clarity and performance, but it might be...

Comment: Well, unless I'm misunderstanding... they would need all of the Columns filled in the first, a price for each day... the same info would take 7 rows of data in the second model would only take 1 for the first.

Comment: @holden: Ah, that wasn't clear that there would always be a price for each day.

Comment: yeah... sorry.  I should have elaborated more.  None of the fields could ever be empty, in either model.